# How to diagnose or repair data SSD on Ubuntu

Tags: hard-drive

I have this problem with a 2 TB SSD:

I'm running an OwnCloud server app on Ubuntu server which is a virtual machine under Windows Server 2012 as host. From host system have Ubuntu 20 GB part of RAID for system and one 2TB SSD for OwnCloud app and data. All data are periodically backed up to another place. All was working fine.

After Windows Server updates I have needed to restart the host machine. Therefore I stopped all virtual machines but for Ubuntu server with OwnCloud I used the red stop-button from Hyper-V manager, not the shutdown command in Ubuntu. After restarting the host system I started all virtuals except Ubuntu. When starting, some test or repair procedure started and ran for a long long time (I left it running for 1 day, then I stopped it.) It was scanning/repairing some blocks and at the end of each block I see:

```
... sd_revalidate_disk+...
... sd_probe_async+...
... async_run_entry_fn+...
... process_one_work+...
... ? process_one_work+...
... worker_thread+...
... ? kthread_create_on_node+...
```

and line with code and three lines of hexadecimal numbers

When I disconnect the 2 TB SSD in the settings of the virtual machine, Ubuntu looks for this drive for 1:30 min, but without procedure above.

When I install a new virtual machine with Ubuntu, all is running OK until I connect this drive in setting up the VM. Immediately it starts testing/repairing.

Is there another way to scan & repair HDD? From some Live-CD with Ubuntu or some tools? Best way? Or do I need to wait a few days for the process? Or is the SSD defective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're a Ubuntu beginner, I'll try and keep this as simple as possible. I'm going to have to make some assumptions about your knowledge level and experience, and about the exact configuration of your SSD.

Ubuntu is not able to properly mount the 2TB SSD, and normally I'd ask that you try and fsck (file system check) the drive, but instructing you on how to do this is terse, and I don't think the SSD would respond properly.

You indicate that you have backups for the apps/data from the SSD, yes? If so, try to format the SSD as NTFS, **FROM WINDOWS**.

If that fails, you may have a defective SSD.

If this works, boot Ubuntu. It may give a failure message when it tries to mount the 2TB disk that is normally **probably** EXT4 format. If Ubuntu won't fully boot because of this, you'll have to edit **/etc/fstab** to temporarily comment out the mount for the SSD. If it does fully boot, use gparted to lay down a new GPT partition table and EXT4 partition on the SSD. Then use **blkid** to determine the new UUID for the drive. You'll need to edit **/etc/fstab** again, re-enabling the SSD mount, and changing the UUID to the new value. Then you can mount the SSD and restore from your backups.

Does this scare you off? Do you have the experience to do this? If you have questions, please ask, but understand this IS somewhat complicated.

Comment: I can better clarify: 1. I have backup of data, no OwnCloud app and structure of users with rights, 2. formatting SSD was: sudo mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1, 3. SDD IS NOW mountable from live-CD with Ubuntu, 4. I can see folder owncloud-data, but have not permit (can use chown..), 5. How to fully scan and repair?, 6. Can I backup all content of SSD, replace SSD with another disc and restore orig. content? 7. re-formatting is the last chance for me ;-) --- edit /etc/fstab to temporarily comment... is good idea, I mainly need to know where is the problem..

Comment: OK, since you can mount the SSD using the Live-CD, open a terminal and type **sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb1**, and change the /dev to the correct mount point if you need to. Cheers, Al

Comment: I am trying it..

Comment: It is working, seems to be finish tomorrow.. (better var.) Thx

Comment: "change the /dev to the correct mount point"...do not understand

Comment: Ohh - finished, but: "Warning: File system has still errors". Running again. (Maybee my "no" as answer to "Lost/Found not founded, create?)

Comment: If you're fscking now, then the mount point of /dev/sdb1 is correct. If fsck can't fix the problems, you need to format the drive, hope it takes it, and restore from backup. Cheers, Al

Comment: Now finished without warning. I can close live-CD and start Ubuntu with OwnCloud...

Comment: Yes, give it a try. If you have luck, please report back here, and also vote/accept my answer, if you can. Cheers, Al

Comment: No good news :-( No change, still is scanning and repairing something. I think that the best way for me now is to copy all content to another disc (I have empty area prepared) and try to swap new for old.

Comment: The **content** may be the problem. It's probably corrupt. What is doing the scanning, Owncloud? Shutdown Owncloud and see if the scanning/repairing stops. If you do change disks, which I don't think will help, remember to edit /etc/fstab with the new uuid for the new disk. Cheers, Al

Comment: No, see beginning, when I am running Ubuntu **without** OwnCloud with SDD as 2nd disc, the problem is the same! OK, tomorrow I will try swap the disks.. (and report here..) Thx

Comment: Now I have formatted and mounted new hdd, data (70GB) are copying...

Comment: Copying done --> swap discs in Hyper-V manager (new hdd is 2nd as was old ssd - no edit in fstab is needed) --> start --> **OwnCloud IS O.K. !!!** --- Now I can remove SSD and test it... But first, more important step is done! --- Thank you for cooperation!

Comment: Glad you got it going. You can install SMART tools (gsmartcontrol)  in Ubuntu or Windows, are run the SMART diagnostics on the drive. Cheers, Al